# Count how many discord.js PMs went through

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Is it possible to count how many messages a bot sent to user's PM?

I'm creating a bot that notifies the users of a server related announcement. (I know this may be considered as spam, in fact users can choose to receive PMs or not)

I have this so far:

```js
let roleCount = message.guild.roles.cache.get(Role.id).members.size;

message.guild.roles.cache.get(Role.id).members.forEach((member) =>
  member.send(embed).catch(async (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    message.reply("I couldn't PM one or more users");
  }),
);
message.channel.send(`I sent a PM to ${roleCount} users`);
```

As you can see, the final message counts how many members there are in a role, and not how many members received the PM.

How can I count how many members didn't receive the PM? After that I can simply do a subtraction (roleCount - PMs that went through).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a counter to track the successful and unsuccessful messages. As `member.send` is asynchronous, you need to resolve the promises first. I used a `Promise.all` to wait for every message to be sent and only send the message with the results once it's finished.

If the message is sent successfully, just increase `counters.success`; if it errors out, increase `counters.error` instead.

```js
let roleId = 'XXXXXXX';
// don't rely on cache, fetch the role instead
let role = await message.guild.roles.fetch(roleId);
let total = role.members.size;

let counters = { success: 0, error: 0 };

// don't forget to wait for every message to be sent
await Promise.all(
  role.members.map(async (member) => {
    try {
      await member.send(embed);
      counters.success += 1;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      counters.error += 1;
    }
  }),
);

message.channel.send(
  `I've sent PMs to ${total} users. ${counters.success} successful, ${counters.error} unsuccessful`,
);
```

[image]

Comment: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Yep, you need to make sure the parent function is an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). Something like `client.on('message', async (message) => { ...` or `module.exports = async (client, Discord) => { ...`, etc. But I'm not sure where your current code is.

Comment: Where should I put it? https://pastebin.com/Bvv3r9Gc

Comment: Here => `async execute (message) {`

Answer (score -1):

```
let roleCount = message.guild.roles.cache.get(Role.id).members.size;
let errorCounter = 0;    
    message.guild.roles.cache.get(Role.id).members.forEach(member => member.send(embed).catch(async err => {
        console.log(err);
        errorCounter++;
        message.reply("I couldn't PM one or more users");
    }));
    message.channel.send(`I sent a PM to ${roleCount} users`)
    console.log('times the error callback was called;',errorCounter);
```

Comment: The count stays 0

Comment: I disabled my DMs to test the code. The console outputs the error but the count stays the same